# Deploy specific jars with the maven deploy plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I have 3 jars:

- service.jar
- service-exec.jar
- service-tests.jar

I only want to deploy service.jar and service-tests.jar, this **works** fine with:

```
mvn --settings settings.xml -Drevision=1.0-SNAPSHOT generate-sources install
mvn --settings settings.xml -Drevision=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dfile=target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dfiles=target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar -DgroupId=de.mycomp -DartifactId=service -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Durl=https://nexus/ -DrepositoryId=nexus.de -Dclassifiers=tests -Dtypes=test-jar deploy:deploy-file
```

But when I use:

```
<plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.2</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                                    <phase>none</phase>
                                </execution>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>files-deploy</id>
                                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <repositoryId>nexus.de</repositoryId>
                                        <url>https://nexus/</url>
                                        <file>target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
                                        <files>target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar</files>
                                        <classifiers>tests</classifiers>
                                        <types>test-jar</types>
                                        <groupId>de.mycomp</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
```

And then use

```
mvn --settings settings.xml -Drevision=1.0-SNAPSHOT generate-sources deploy
```

It deploys all 3 jars and then in addition the service-test.jar again.

Why does the plugin with this config still deploys all 3 + 1 jars? Shouldn't it be the same then the command??

Comment: If you have configured it correctly you don't need to define the maven-deploy-plugin using the deploy-file goal...it whould work with just using `mvn deploy` but unfortunately I don't see the whole pom file of your project....

Comment: @khmarbaise Well in the beginning I used just deploy and it just deployed all 3 jars. What do you mean with "if you have configured it correctly" if I configured WHAT correctly? According to the docu (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) the normal deploy goal "is used to automatically install the artifact, its pom **and the attached artifacts** produced by a particular project" what it absolutely does but I want to exclude the exec jar. I can you show more of the pom on Monday, which parts to you need?